# How to trigger a rollout restart on deployment resource from controller-runtime

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, client-go, operator-sdk, kubebuilder

I have been using kubebuilder for writing custom controller, and aware of Get(), Update(), Delete() methods that it provides. But Now I am looking for a method which mimic the behaviour of `kubectl rollout restart deployment`. If there is no such direct method then I am looking for correct way to mimic the same.

```golang
type CustomReconciler struct {
    client.Client
    Log    logr.Logger
    Scheme *runtime.Scheme
}

func (r *CustomReconciler) Reconcile(ctx context.Context, req ctrl.Request) (ctrl.Result, error) {
    configMap := &v1.ConfigMap{}
    err = r.Get(ctx, req.namespacedName, configMap)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(err, "Failed to GET configMap")
        return ctrl.Result{}, err
    }
```

Say in above code I read a deployment name from the configmap and rollout restart the same as follows:

```golang
    val := configMap.Data["config.yml"]
    config := Config{}
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(val), &config); err != nil {
        logger.Error(err, "failed to unmarshal config data")
        return ctrl.Result{}, err
    }

    // Need equivalent of following
    // r.RolloutRestart(config.DeploymentName)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all cases where you wish to replicate `kubectl` behavior, the answer is always to increase its verbosity and it'll show you exactly -- sometimes down to the wire payloads -- what it is doing.

For rollout restart, one will find that it just [bumps an annotation](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes@v1.23.3/-/blob/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/polymorphichelpers/objectrestarter.go?L41) on the Deployment/StatefulSet/whatever and that causes the outer object to be "different," and triggering a reconciliation run

You can squat on their annotation, or you can make up your own, or you can use a label change -- practically any "meaningless" change will do

Comment: yes get that.. but I was expecting more concrete answer.